# Book about a young man who wants to win a school science fair, who goes through water portals and speaks to spiritual beings

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this book in 2021.

It's based in Washington I believe. It's about a young man who is really intelligent and wants to win a science fair contest for his school. At the same time he kayaks to his house a lot and end ups finding these water portals where he gets transferred to somewhere else and ends up talking with spiritual beings.

But there’s a bad guy from his town after him because he wants to be able to go through the portals. He’s also a judge of his science fair project. His science fair project had to do with water and molecules and how he can manipulate them or something like that. There's also some reflective thing he finds on his dad's old boat that the bad guy wants. There’s also an old man and dog that help him the whole time from him town. The dog ends protecting him and being special.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall anyone's name?  Was this a physical book or an e-book?  Anything stand out about the cover art?